# QML Loader doesn't change its active state

Tags: qt, qml, loader

In the following *QML* code:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainItem
    
    width: 1024
    height: 600
    
    property bool firstVal: true
    property bool secondVal: true
    property bool thirdVal: true
    
    // HOME PAGE
    Loader {
        id: homeLoader
        sourceComponent: homeComponent
        active: false
        visible: false
    }
    
    Component {
        id:homeComponent
        
        PageHome {
            id: home
            visible: true;
            
            onSgnSetFirst: { // signal sgnSetFirst(val)
                firstVal = val
            }
            
            onSgnSetSecond: { // signal sgnSetSecond(val)
                secondVal = val
            }
            
            onSgnSetThird: { // signal sgnSetThird(val)
                thirdVal = val
            }
        }
    }
    
    // FIRST PAGE
    Loader {
        id: firstLoader
        sourceComponent: firstComponent
        active: false
        visible: false
    }
    
    Component {
        id: firstComponent
        
        PageFirst {
            id:firstPage
            visible: true;
        }
    }
    
    // SECOND PAGE
    Loader {
        id: secondLoader
        sourceComponent: secondComponent
        active: false
        visible: false
    }
    
    Component {
        id: secondComponent
        
        PageSecond {
            id:secondPage
            visible: true;
        }
    }
    
    // THIRD PAGE
    Loader {
        id: thirdLoader
        sourceComponent: thirdComponent
        active: false
        visible: false
    }
    
    
    Component {
        id: thirdComponent
        
        PageThird {
            id:thirdPage
            visible: true;
        }
    }
    
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangleMain
        
        width: 1024
        height: 600
        color: "transparent"
        
        state: "rms_HOME"
        
        states: [
            State {
                name: ""
                
                PropertyChanges {target: homeLoader;     active:  false}
                PropertyChanges {target: firstLoader;    active:  false}
                PropertyChanges {target: secondLoader;   active:  false}
                PropertyChanges {target: thirdLoader;    active:  false}
                
                PropertyChanges {target: homeLoader;     visible: false}
                PropertyChanges {target: firstLoader;    visible: false}
                PropertyChanges {target: secondLoader;   visible: false}
                PropertyChanges {target: thirdLoader;    visible: false}
            },
            
            // HOME PAGE
            State {
                name: "rms_HOME"
                
                PropertyChanges {target: homeLoader;     active:  true     }
                PropertyChanges {target: firstLoader;    active:  firstVal }
                PropertyChanges {target: secondLoader;   active:  secondVal}
                PropertyChanges {target: thirdLoader;    active:  thirdVal }
                
                PropertyChanges {target: homeLoader;     visible: true }
                PropertyChanges {target: firstLoader;    visible: false}
                PropertyChanges {target: secondLoader;   visible: false}
                PropertyChanges {target: thirdLoader;    visible: false}
            },
            
            // FIRST PAGE
            State {
                name: "rms_FIRST"
                
                PropertyChanges {target: homeLoader;     active:  false}
                PropertyChanges {target: firstLoader;    active:  true }
                PropertyChanges {target: secondLoader;   active:  false}
                PropertyChanges {target: thirdLoader;    active:  false}
                
                PropertyChanges {target: homeLoader;     visible: false}
                PropertyChanges {target: firstLoader;    visible: true }
                PropertyChanges {target: secondLoader;   visible: false}
                PropertyChanges {target: thirdLoader;    visible: false}
            },
            
            // SECOND PAGE
            State {
                name: "rms_SECOND"
                
                PropertyChanges {target: homeLoader;     active:  false}
                PropertyChanges {target: firstLoader;    active:  false}
                PropertyChanges {target: secondLoader;   active:  true }
                PropertyChanges {target: thirdLoader;    active:  false}
                
                PropertyChanges {target: homeLoader;     visible: false}
                PropertyChanges {target: firstLoader;    visible: false}
                PropertyChanges {target: secondLoader;   visible: true }
                PropertyChanges {target: thirdLoader;    visible: false}
            },
            
            // THIRD PAGE
            State {
                name: "rms_THIRD"
                
                PropertyChanges {target: homeLoader;     active:  false}
                PropertyChanges {target: firstLoader;    active:  false}
                PropertyChanges {target: secondLoader;   active:  false}
                PropertyChanges {target: thirdLoader;    active:  true }
                
                PropertyChanges {target: homeLoader;     visible: false}
                PropertyChanges {target: firstLoader;    visible: false}
                PropertyChanges {target: secondLoader;   visible: false}
                PropertyChanges {target: thirdLoader;    visible: true }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

There are four screens: **home page**, **first page**, **second page** and **third page**.

Each of them is managed by a Loader. Each Loader is enabled/disabled by means the `state` property of the `rectangleMain` item.

When the `rectangleMain.state` property is set to `rms_HOME`, the `homeLoader` is active and visible while the others Loader are not visible but can be active or not depending on the `firstVal`, `secondVal` and `thirdVal`.

The logic works well only if the `rectangleMain.state` property change from `rms_FIRST` or `rms_SECOND` or `rms_THIRD` to `rms_HOME` but it doesn't work if the `rectangleMain.state` property is equal to `rms_HOME` and  `firstVal` or `secondVal` or `thirdVal` change its value.

Why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The declaration syntax for `bool` properties seem wrong on the top of the file. They are not being declared or initialized correctly.

Comment: The three `bool` properties are correctly initialized in my original code. I forgot to insert them in the post when I copied and pasted the code

Comment: You can still EDIT the question and fix the code. Most people usually ignore questions that share code that can't even be compiled correctly. Make sure the code you share is **minimal**, **has no build errors and reproduces the behavior you are trying to understand/solve**. This is my last message on this question. Good luck!

Comment: One more thing you have to do is to remove parentheses from signals `onSgnSetFirst`, `onSgnSetSecond`, `onSgnSetThird` in `homeComponent` component

Comment: As @Mike said, don't use parentheses like that. Also don't use `var` properties when you actually mean `bool`. If the properties are `var` they will not automatically generate onVarChanged signals when you modify their value.

Comment: Also, can I suggest you take a look at something like a [StackView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html) instead of using multiple loaders and states the way you're doing it.

Comment: I tried out your edited code. The only problem now is that in the rms_HOME state, you still force the Loader's visible properties to be false. If you bind the visible properties to your `firstVal`, `secondVal`, etc then it works fine.

Comment: @JarMan, I need to keep multiple Loaders active simultaneously even if only one of them is visible at a time. This because in each Loader there is a Timer and a Chart component used to sample e show (by means the LineSeries component) some numerical variables. Is the use of multiple loaders a wrong way to do this?  Thanks

Comment: Then I'm really confused what you want now. You are already setting the `active` property. That works fine, whether they are visible or not. So what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I´ve made an minimal implementation for you. It uses the loaders in a usefull way and achievs what you want from what i can tell. Here you go:

```
    import QtQuick 2.0

ApplicationWindow
{
  
    //because your example is not working i am trying to implement it like this...
    //I`ve been testing it with rectangles and it works.
    //From what I see you can achieve your goal if you do it like follows:

    id: root

    width: 1024
    height: 600

    property string currentPage: "home"
  
    // use one loader to load the current component that you need, dont use multiple ones
    Loader
    {
        id:pageLoader
        
        active: true
        visible: true
        
        // here we switch the source of the loader depending on root.currentPage
        sourceComponent: {
            switch(root.currentPage) {
              case "home":
                return homeComponent
              case "firstVal":
                return firstComponent
              case "secondVal":
                return secondComponent
              case "thirdVal"
                return thirdComponent
              default: return homeComponent
            }
        }
    }

    Component
    {
        id:homeComponent

        PageHome
        {
            id:home
            visible: true;
          
            //here we now change the root.currentPage to tell the loader what to load.
            //it would be nicer to use enums here but I dont want to make it too complicated.
            
           anchors.fill: parent

        //here we now change the root.currentPage to tell the loader what to load.
        //it would be nicer to use enums here.
        
        onSgnSetFirst:  // signal sgnSetFirst(val)
        {
          root.currentPage = "firstVal";
        }

        onSgnSetSecond: // signal sgnSetSecond(val)
        {
          root.currentPage = "secondVal";
        }

        onSgnSetThird:  // signal sgnSetThird(val)
        {
          root.currentPage = "thirdVal";
        }
    }
    

    Component
    {
        id:firstComponent

        PageFirst
        {
            id:firstPage
            visible: true;
        }
    }

    Component
    {
        id:secondComponent

        PageSecond
        {
            id:secondPage
            visible: true;
        }
    }
          
    Component
    {
        id:thirdComponent

        PageThird
        {
            id:thirdPage
            visible: true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize. My original code is very complex so I couldn't copy it as is. 

I need to keep multiple loaders active at the same time but only one of them visible. 

However, my doubt is about updating the `PropertyChanges`. Referring to my previous example what I want to know is what happens if the `state` property remains fixed at the `rms_HOME` and one of the properties `firstVal`, `secondVal` or `thirdVal` change its value.

Thanks

Comment: @nataut Ok, I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve to be honest and I don't think that multiple loaders and setting them visible/active is very clean design of code - but I might be wrong since I dont understand the problem fully.

Looking at your Problem again have you tried setting restoreEntryValues : false in your PropertyChanges? Does it effect the outcome?

Comment: I tried to set `restoreEntryValues: false` but nothing changes. I have to load four `Loader` of which only one has to be displayed. Each `Loader` loads a qml component in which there are `Timer`, `Chart` and `LineSeries` used to sample and display values of some variables. The four `Loader` have to be all active because I have to keep in memory the graphs with all their data. What happens to me is that only one `Loader` is really loaded (the first that starts the loading process), the others are not. I tried also to set `asynchronous: true` in each `Loader` but nothing changes